# How to use this subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to see if time is below 0 with this query

```
select *
from voorwerp
where (Select (((Cast(((DATEADD(dd, looptijd, datum)) - getdate()) as float) * 24.0)*60.0)*60.0) AS tijd from voorwerp) <= 0
```

I get this error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: min time, max time what?  you're getting a time value for each record in voorwerp, you can only return 1.

Comment: No need for the subquery -- just use `where calculatedfield <= 0`...

Comment: `WHERE CAST(DATEADD(dd, looptijd, datum) - GETDATE() AS FLOAT) <= 0`

Comment: @sgeddes thanks that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need subquery and in order to avoid the use of functions in the where you can use the CTE.

Try this:

```
;with CTE

as

(

SELECT
       --you need to specify a name for your column,

       CAST(DATEADD(dd, looptijd, datum) - GETDATE() AS FLOAT) as TIJD

FROM voorwerp
<= 0

)

Select 
         --you need to specify a name for your column
From CTE
WHERE TIJD <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem rewrite your SQL like so:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM voorwerp v
WHERE (
      SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd, looptijd, datum) - GETDATE() AS FLOAT) as tijd
      FROM voorwerp
      ) <= 0
```